# I m looking fo a regex that not permit more than star character consecutive

Tags: regex

Hello  I ' m looking  for a regex that not permit  write   than more star character consecutive and not permit  a string with just more star character.
for example  :

```
a*g*h*  // is allowed
***** // is not allowed
* //is not allowed
*a //. is allowed
```

in this moment I have this regex :`^([^*]*\*{1,2}[^*]*|\*[^*]*\*{1,2}[^*]*|\*\*[^*]+\*{1,2}[^*]*|[^*]*)$`

Somebody can help me  pls ?

Comment: Use `^(?!\*$|.*\*\*)` as negative lookahead

Comment: Hi, did [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825817/3832970) work for you? If yes, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that works.

```
^(?!\*{2})[^\\\s][^*\\\s]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*\\\s]*)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a lookahead condition with alternation:

```
^(?!\*$|.*\*\*).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pIffen/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!\*$|.*\*\*)`: Negative lookahead assertion that fails the match if we have just `*` before end or have `**` anywhere in the input ahead
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
^(?!\*+$)[^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pILStJ/1/) (where `[^*]` is replaced with `[^*\n]` to stay on the same line since the demo is run against a single multiline string rather than a set of separate strings).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\*+$)` - no `*` only string allowed
- `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\*(?!\*)` - a `*` not followed with another `*`
  - `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `$` - end of string.